# How do I remove an event handler created with jQuery.bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `div` to which I want to bind two scroll functions, and after a certain function I want to unbind one of them.

```
<div id="div1" class="mydivs">
something
</div>
<div id="div2">Some crap here</div>

<script>
function check_scroll () { $('#div2').empty(); }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mydivs').bind('scroll', check_scroll);
});

function fun() {
if (conditionsMet) {
    $('#msgxlthis_content').bind('scroll', function(event) {
       alert("done");
    });
}
}
</script>
```

As soon as fun() is called and `conditionsMet` turns true the alerting function is attached with the element but the previous one(`check_scroll`) stops functioning.

I want to bind both the function to my div. What to do?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: The question suffers from several contradictions.

Comment: Can you possibly provide [a functional example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue? Adding another event binding should not disable or "break" those bound before it. There's likely another source for the issue.

Comment: None of this really makes a lot of sense.Please create a demo that replicates issue and provide better description of the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you use `unbind` to remove a handler, but looks like your question is not about unbinding (after further reading it)

First, please define "stops functioning".

Try debugging and checking if the execution enters the `check_scroll` function at all